# What is the relationship between the various Android OpenGL-related classes?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

What's the relationship between:

- android.opengl
- javax.microedition.khronos.egl
- javax.microedition.khronos.opengles

I can't tell from the Android documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This packages:

- javax.microedition.khronos.egl
- javax.microedition.khronos.opengles

Defines the Java interfaces to EGL and OpenGL ES, while android.opengl is a concrete implementation of those interfaces.